# Web Background Tasks API vs Web Workers API vs setTimeout() for sending analytics data to backend server using POST request

Tags: javascript, http-post, settimeout, web-worker

Currently I send analytics data like user activity data to the backend server using `HTTP POST` request. And I am concerned about my application's performance and smoothness of user actions and input.

So I want to increase performance and smoothness of application user experince. For that I have 3 choices.

1. [`Background Tasks API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Background_Tasks_API) (runs on a same thread)
2. [`Web Workers API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) (runs on different thread)
3. [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) (runs on same thread)

What would be pro and cons of these approaches and which one would be best for sending multiple HTTP POST call one by one?

Comment: There is no reason why making HTTP POST call would impact the performance or smoothness of the application, unless you submit the page, or you use a [synchronous `XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#parameters). AJAX is by definition asynchronous (it's what the first "A" stands for). Neither of the three choices will make any difference in that regard.

Comment: Note that you got your list wrong, 1 runs on the same thread, 2 runs on a different one.

Comment: @Kaiido: I have updated. Dont know I put wrong details. Thanks.